# How to load certain aspect of json file to rdd easily

Tags: python, json, list, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a json file with over a million rows, so I am trying to minimize the number of times I have to run through it all to get one aspect of it into an rdd.

Right now, I load each row into a list:

```
with open('in/json-files/sites.json') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Then, I make another list and import the aspect into that:

```
for line in range(1,len(data)):
        data_companies.append(data[line]['company'])
```

Then, I parallelize this into an rdd so that I can analyze it. I am worried about how much memory this will take up, so is there an easier and faster way to do this? I have tried loading the json file like this, but it wont work:

```
data.append(json.loads(line['company'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your data is structured(JSON), you can look into Spark-SQL

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-programming-guide.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-data-sources-json.html

You can directly load your JSON into a dataframe and look for the particular column to do your analysis